# External CSS not working for span tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

When I use external CSS for underlining the word "pro", I'm unable to do so, whereas when I use inline CSS in `<span>` tag, it works perfectly fine. I have been trying to debug this code since past 2 hours. I'm still unable to do so. Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: add your code so we can see what you did

Comment: how do you include your css

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark important in your external css file to apply any overlay css on your html

like if you are tring to apply background color for span tag from external css

your css must be like this

```
span{
 background-color:#000 !important;     /*EDIT: important to !important
}
```

Comment: Singh sahab... Its !important; oor kaissa chal raha hai....

Comment: yeah right @ImranRafiqRather apan ka sab thik ap batye kaisa chal rha hai

Answer (score 0):

The `inline-style` has higher specificity than the external CSS selector. That's why it always takes precedence in the code when both are used.

However, if you are using only the external CSS and your CSS not being applied, you need to check few things.

1. Whether your external CSS is correctly linked to your HTML page.
2. And if so Are you using the Selector correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use !important css property between style rule property value  and semicolon in the external style sheet to increase its priority like following :

```
Selector {property :property-value !important;}
```